# MudBlazor autocomplete not searching case sensitive. .NET 6 Blazor Server App

Tags: autocomplete, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, mudblazor

Hi I have problems making MudBLazor autocomplete to search a given list.
This list of countries is fetched from a service as List.
I have tried changing the StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase to other culture without any luck!

Here is the code:
I really dont understand why autocomplete is not returning a smaller list matching the search string (value). It only matches with case-sensitive letters like Albania not albania.

```
  <MudCard Style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 600px;">
                            <MudCardContent>

                                <label>Sending from:</label>
                                <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="Country" @bind-Value="@userCountry" SearchFunc="@SearchFromCountries" />
                            </MudCardContent>
                        </MudCard>
```

```
@code {

    private string userCountry, userToCountry;
    public IEnumerable<CountriesCurrencies> countries;
  
    private List<string> countryList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        userCountry = await countryService.GetUserCountry(userId);
        countries = await countryService.GetCountriesList();
        countryList = GetCountriesList();
    }

    private List<string> GetCountriesList()
    {
        countryList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var country in countries)
        {
            countryList.Add(country.Country);
        }
        return countryList;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchFromCountries(string value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return countryList;

        return await Task.FromResult(countryList.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor you code as follows and check that you are returning the correct list:

```cs
    private Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchFromCountries(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return countryList;

        var list = countryList.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
       // break point here to check what you are returning
        return Task.FromResult(list);

    }
```

Comment: I tried that already, even created a small list of strings but the search isn’t responding to each character only matching the whole word and in case sensitive

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  I've just looked at the `MudAutocomplete` code and it displays the list of items returned by `SearchFunc`.  So to prove what I believe is happening return a fixed `IEnumerable<String>` and see what is displayed.

Comment: Well if I understod why i would have solved this a long time ago. I am uzing Blazor Server, what i have discovered during debugging is that the searchfunc is not called each time i enter new character in the autocomplete box. It only suggest when it hits a match, another strange thing is that it doesnt match "england" but it matches "England" if I have "england" in the list it doesnt match anything. So i also checked that it could be something with the CurrentCulture settings but iam not sure.

Comment: Based on what you've said I suggest you address the problem to MudBlazor.  Not many of the answerer's on here use MudBlazor so your chances of getting an answer are small.  I don't.  Good luck

Comment: I found the problem, I needed to update another object before returning the IEnumerable<string> in the searchfunction that other object update was also using a .Where(...) statement this blocked the search. Now its fixed. Thanks for the help.